# canOpen and open methods of UIApplication returning different results for a FaceTime url

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using iPhone 4 running iOS 7.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://phoneNumber"]];
```

returns **YES**.

but

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://phoneNumber"]];
```

returns **NO**.

I am not able to figure out what is the problem. In iPad it is working fine.

Comment: The same phone number works on one device and fails on another?

Comment: I wanted to set UI state based on if device can make facetime call. Yes, number was same.

Comment: In theory they can be different as `canOpenURL:` checks only the URL scheme, not the URL content. Is there a configuration issue with FaceTime on one device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain)!
I checked FaceTime configuration on device, it was not enabled. I enabled it by going into ***Settings->General->Restrictions*** on iPhone 4(running iOS 7) and finally openURL returned YES and FaceTime call was initiated.

I wonder if there is some api which tells that if FaceTime is enabled or not?